# Asynchronous confusion. Processing an API response and losing my grasp on what is happening in this code

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I've gotten lost inside my own head about how to best structure this function.
This code below is mostly correct, I just stubbed out a few of the functions at the bottom, not important.

What is supposed to happen:

1. My node app runs at a certain time and calls `refreshDevices()`
2. The function fetches a JSON payload from an API
3. The function loops over elements in that payload and checks if there is a record already
4. If there is no record, one is created, if there is then it is updated
5. After this is run a log entry is created logging the number of changes.

My issue is the log entry happens prior to any of the record checks taking place... my log shows 0 added & 0 updated.
I've tried re-writing the code to use an inline async/await function but I think that is effectively the same thing as below.

How am I supposed to structure this function to do what I've said.
I am finding the mix of async and sync very confusing to wrap my head around.

- I even tried adding the log entry bit to happen in a `.finally()`
  block at the end, but that was executing before the checks happened.
- I have tried this using both `forEach` and `map`.

```
refreshDevices(_timespan) {  
  const status = {
    added: 0,
    updated: 0,
  };

  // Standard API fetch & json() conversion
  fetch(`https://api.example.com/test&timespan=${timespan}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((JSON) => {
      JSON.forEach((device) => {
        findDevice(device._id)
        .then(record => {
          if (!record) {
            addDeviceRecord(device);
            status.added++;
          } else {
            deviceSeen(device._id);
            status.updated++;
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('Error!');
        });
      });

      systemlog.log({
        message: 'Refresh',
        data: {
          success: true,
          note: `Added: ${status.added} & updated: ${status.updated}`,
        },
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      systemlog.log({
        message: 'Refresh',
        type: systemlog.logType.ERROR,
        data: {
          success: false,
          note: error,
        },
      });
    });
}

function findDevice(id) {
  return DB('device').findOne({ id }); // this returns is a promise
}

function addDeviceRecord(record) {
  return DB('device').insertOne(record); // this returns is a promise
}

function deviceSeen(id) {
  return DB('device').updateOne({ id }, { $set: { lastSeen: new Date() } }); // this returns is a promise
}
```

This question

Comment: `Promise.all( JSON.map( ... ) ).then( _ => systemlog.log(...`

Comment: you may want to consider renaming the var `JSON` to `data` or something similar, so that you don't obscure the js [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) object

Comment: @csum good point, I hadn't thought of that. thanks!

Comment: @Kaiido that sounds like what elight answered below. I am going to give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have identified, your `system.log` call happens immediately after launching a litany of promises which haven't resolved.

Inside your `refreshDevices(_timespan)` function add an empty array to add each new promise in the `forEach`.

Then modify your code like

```
JSON.forEach((device) => {
            promises.push( // Add this promise to the array
                findDevice(device._id)
                .then(record => {
                    if (!record) {
                        addDeviceRecord(device);
                        status.added++;
                    } else {
                        deviceSeen(device._id);
                        status.updated++;
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Error!');
                });
            ) // end of .push() arg
        });
```

Then use Promise.all() to wait for all promises to be resolved before calling `systemLog.log`, sort of like (pseudo-pseudo code :)

```
Promise.all(promises).then(
            systemlog.log({
                message: 'Refresh',
                data: {
                    success: true,
                    note: `Added: ${status.added} & updated: ${status.updated}`,
                },
            });
        )
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like the way to go, I will have a go at updating my code later. Still getting my head around promises pulling functions out of the stack and things executing out of order. Appreciate the effort with your answer :D

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Async/await` to make the code more readable and use `for of` to iterate over data.

`for of` loop will wait for the first iteration to complete and then go for the second one and so on.

On the other hand forEach is based on callback and so it will execute and register a callback for each iteration in the callback queue and exit and don't wait for the callbacks to complete.

Try this

```
    async refreshDevices(_timespan) {
        const status = {
            added: 0,
            updated: 0,
        };
        // Standard API fetch & json() conversion
        try {
            let response = await fetch(`https://api.example.com/test&timespan=${timespan}`)
            let data= await response.json();
            for (const device of data) {
                try {
                    let record = await findDevice(device._id);
                    if (!record) {
                        addDeviceRecord(device);
                        status.added++;
                    } else {
                        deviceSeen(device._id);
                        status.updated++;
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log('Error!');
                }
            }
            systemlog.log({
                message: 'Refresh',
                data: {
                    success: true,
                    note: `Added: ${status.added} & updated: ${status.updated}`,
                },
            });
        } catch (error) {
            systemlog.log({
                message: 'Refresh',
                type: systemlog.logType.ERROR,
                data: {
                    success: false,
                    note: error,
                },
            });
        }
    }

function findDevice(id) {
    return DB('device').findOne({ id }); // this returns is a promise
}
function addDeviceRecord(record) {
    return DB('device').insertOne(record); // this returns is a promise
}
function deviceSeen(id) {
    return DB('device').updateOne({ id }, { $set: { lastSeen: new Date() } }); // this returns is a promise
}
```

**Alternatively you could also use `promise.all` to wait for all promises to be resolved.**

```
 async refreshDevices(_timespan) {
        const status = {
            added: 0,
            updated: 0,
        };
        // Standard API fetch & json() conversion
        try {
            let response = await fetch(`https://api.example.com/test&timespan=${timespan}`)
            let data = await response.json();
            let promises = data.map(device => {
                return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
                    try {
                        let record = await findDevice(device._id);
                        if (!record) {
                            addDeviceRecord(device);
                            status.added++;
                        } else {
                            deviceSeen(device._id);
                            status.updated++;
                        }
                        resolve();
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log('Error!');
                        reject(error);
                    }
                });
            });
            let result = await Promise.all(promises);
            systemlog.log({
                message: 'Refresh',
                data: {
                    success: true,
                    note: `Added: ${status.added} & updated: ${status.updated}`,
                },
            });
        } catch (error) {
            systemlog.log({
                message: 'Refresh',
                type: systemlog.logType.ERROR,
                data: {
                    success: false,
                    note: error,
                },
            });
        }
    }
function findDevice(id) {
    return DB('device').findOne({ id }); // this returns is a promise
}
function addDeviceRecord(record) {
    return DB('device').insertOne(record); // this returns is a promise
}
function deviceSeen(id) {
    return DB('device').updateOne({ id }, { $set: { lastSeen: new Date() } }); // this returns is a promise
}
```

Comment: This should work, although you are turning multiple async processes into multiple sync processes, as opposed to allowing each promise to run asynchronously and then continuing execution as soon as the final promise is resolved.

Comment: Thanks @Sohail this looks like what I was trying to do (i recoded this function about 5 times and I had one version with async/await everywhere). However, I didn't use `for of` loop which sounds like that was my undoing. I learned something new about the forEach & map functions today... thanks!